# Elegant way to parse console commands in java

Tags: java, command

So im making an application that works via console commands (think of "database new db_name"). Whats the most elegant way to handle this sort of thing?

Heres my little prototype, basicly just tons of switches. I mean it works but it gets kinda messy once I want to add stuff like putting out all the parameters if you pass a wrong one or too few, so im wondering if theres a better option:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (running) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cmd = in.nextLine();

        parseCmd(cmd);
    }
}

private static void parseCmd(String s) {
    String[] cmd = s.split(" ");
    try {
        switch (cmd[0]) {
            case "exit":
                running = false;
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
                break;

            case "database":
                switch (cmd[1]) {
                    case "new":
                        databases.add(new Database(cmd[2]));
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Unknown parameter");
                        break;
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown command");
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        System.out.println("Too few arguments passed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used this library of apache https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html and It worked perfectly

Comment: This question might be better suited to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) since it is already working.  One option which comes to mind for you is to use the command pattern to handle the various commands coming from the console.

Comment: for this cases I like to use enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the *most* elegant way, but I've done something like this a couple of times and came up with this solution.

Make a class for "database" that represents the command, once you find the string "database", you retrieve an instance of this class and pass it the remaining arguments, so it can do the rest of the parsing.

```
class DataBaseCommand implements Command {
    @Override
    public void eval(String[] args) {...}
}
```

You can then keep a static map of these commands mapped to their names:

```
private static final Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

static {
    commands.put("database", new DataBaseCommand());
}
```

```
switch (cmd[0]) {
    case "exit":
        running = false;
        System.out.println("Shutting down...");
        break;
    default:
        if(commands.contains(cmd[0])) {
            commands.get(cmd[0]).eval(cmd);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknown command");
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, its not very bloatish and still allows customization, I think its perfect for this kind of project scale, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a library that does a lot of those command parsing for you, like joptsimple?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [http://jcommander.org/](http://JCommander).Its simple and elegant. In it you can use inbuilt annotations
 e.g Create a class like this using jcommander annotaions

```
@Parameters(commandNames = {"test", "Manages dates"})
public class CommandOption {

    @Parameter(names = {"-e", "--exit"}, description = "bla bla")
    public boolean exit = false;


}

then in main method 


      public static void main(String... args){

        CommandOption opt = new CommandOption();
            JCommander jc = new JCommander(opt);

            jc.parse(args);

    //and now use 
      System.out.println("value" +opt.exit)
    }
```

and then can pass parmaeters as `java class`-e true or maybe better if you can create jar and then  `java -jar 'jar' -e true`